# htaccess denies my page to get style

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using .htaccess in order to sanitize my links.
The links look like:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/home/param2/param3
```

I use an explode function to get my parameters:

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$aPages = explode("/", $url);

if($num >= 0){
    return $aPages[$num];
}
else{
    return $url;
}
```

My htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteRule .* /index.php
```

If my first parameter ('home') is empty, it will redirect to a page saying 'no page found'.
This all works fine, but when I call my stylesheet ('/css/style.css'), the website does the same thing and will not load my stylesheet. How do I fix  this?

Comment: You're redirecting everything to `index.php`

Comment: why people tag html and css for php questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
# Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On
#  Rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: @RickSlinkman I don't have extensive experience with .htaccess, but that's the best I can do. Also, this isn't a php issue.